# Dashed border on table in rotated div - How do I remove it?

Tags: css, angularjs, rotation, html-table, border

When rotating a div that contains a table, the table has a dashed border around the cells. I would post pics, but I don't have 10 reputation - have never posted a question before. Anyway, when the div is not rotated the dashed lines disappear!

I have tried everything to remove this border but can't figure it out. Angularjs is being used, as you can see below. I have not included it in the code as I don't alter anything CSS-wise in it. But if anyone deems it important please let me know and I will add it.

HTML code:

```
<div data-ng-switch='vm.seats.levelSelected' style="overflow: auto; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 300px; text-align: center;">
   <div data-ng-repeat='base in vm.seats' data-ng-show='vm.seats.levelSelected == base.level.levelId' style='position: relative; display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;'>
       <span style='font-size: large;'>{{base.level.levelName}}</span>
       <div data-ng-repeat='section in base.sections' style='position: absolute;' data-ng-style="{'top': section.section.sectionTop + 'px', 'left': section.section.sectionLeft + 'px',
               '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + section.section.sectionRotation + 'deg)',
               '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + section.section.sectionRotation + 'deg)',
               '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + section.section.sectionRotation + 'deg)',
               '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + section.section.sectionRotation + 'deg)',
               'transform': 'rotate(' + section.section.sectionRotation + 'deg)'}">
           <table id="Seating" ng-model='rowBox'>
               <tr data-ng-repeat='row in section.rows'>
                   <td data-ng-repeat='seat in row.seats' style='padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; line-height: 70%; border: none; outline: none;' data-ng-style="{'background-color': seat.priceColor }">
                       <input type='checkbox' ng-show='seat.statusId > 1' ng-disabled='vm.ShouldDisable(seat.statusId)' style='margin: 1px 1px 1px 2px;'
                                data-ng-style="{'cursor': vm.SetCursor(seat.statusId), 'border': 'none'}" id='{{seat.seatId}}' name='{{seat.seatId}}'
                                title='{{seat.sectionName}}, {{seat.row}}, {{seat.seatText}}, {{seat.priceGroupName}} - {{seat.statusName}}|{seat.seatId}}'
                                ng-model='seat.cbStatus'
                                ng-change='vm.SetCart(seat.seatId, $parent.$index,$parent.$parent.$index, $parent.$parent.$parent.$index,$index)' />
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
table#Seating {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
}
table#Seating td {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle can display what you mean?

Comment: I have never done a JSFiddle, I will see what I can do.